# How to see the isomorphism $k(V)=k(V_1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $V\subset X$ is a variety, where X is either projective or affine. Let $V_1\subset V$ be any non-empty open subset of $V$. Then $k(V)=k(V_1)$, the field of rational functions are isomorphic.

I am stuck after the following steps:

Define $\frac{f}{g} \mapsto \frac{f|_{V_1}}{g|_{V_1}}$. Since $\frac{f}{g}\in k(V)$, $g$ is defined on some dense open subset of $V$, which intersects $V_1$. So $g|_{V_1}$ is not zero on $V_1$. One can check the map is well-defined, and is surjective because if $\frac{f}{g}$ is defined on $V_1$, then the domains of $f,g$ are open in $V_1$, thus open in $V$. I am stuck at injectivity. If $\frac{f|_{V_1}}{g|_{V_1}}=0$, $f$ vanishes on $V_1$. But does $f$ vanish on $V$?

Or am I wrong in one of the steps above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of vanishing of $f$ in $X $ is a closed subset of $X$. Now it contains $V_1$. $V_1$ being dense in $V$, $f$ vanishes on $V$, so you are done.